# Is it possible to save entity with both new and existing data?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class TestEntity1 {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "entity1_generator",
            sequenceName = "entity1_generator",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "entity1_generator"
    )
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_id")
    private TestEntity2 ent;

    public TestEntity1() {
    }

    public TestEntity1(TestEntity2 ent) {
        this.ent = ent;
    }

    public TestEntity1(long id, TestEntity2 ent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ent = ent;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TestEntity2 getEnt() {
        return ent;
    }

    public void setEnt(TestEntity2 ent) {
        this.ent = ent;
    }
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
public class TestEntity2 {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "entity2_generator",
            sequenceName = "entity2_generator",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "entity2_generator"
    )
    private long id;

    private String str;

    public TestEntity2() {
    }

    public TestEntity2(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public TestEntity2(long id, String str) {
        this.id = id;
        this.str = str;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do both:

```java
repository1.save(new TestEntity1(new TestEntity2("2")));
```

and

```java
repository1.save(new TestEntity1(repository2.findAll().get(0)));
```

but the problem is that these two ways of saving entities don't work at once.
I can use either one or another.
I tried to use different combinations of annotations, CascadeType.ALL or Merge etc, but nothing works. Always one of the lines above throws exception
Is it even possible to use both of these lines:

```java
repository1.save(new TestEntity1(new TestEntity2("2")));
repository1.save(new TestEntity1(repository2.findAll().get(0)));
```

or do I have to decide which one I want to use?

EDIT:

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.jakub.model.Entity2; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.jakub.model.Entity2

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy110.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakub.service.EntityService.saveEntity1(EntityService.java:39)
    at com.jakub.service.EntityServiceTest.test1(EntityServiceTest.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.jakub.model.Entity2
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:798)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:766)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy107.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:624)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:638)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 76 more
```

and here is the test class:

```java
package com.jakub.service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class EntityServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EntityService service;

    @Test
    void test1() {
        service.saveEntity1();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, either inline, instantiating or recovering the data as you asked.

When specifying a connection between 2 (or more) classes it is good to create the full mapping at first and then hone it after undertanding it fully (at least that is how I think).

For your case I've reproduced the entities and created a simple persistence with spring-boot with mysql (don't have postgres here, sry) to make the POC.

The entities:

Entity1

```
package com.jakub.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author André Fróes
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Entity2 entity2;

    public Entity1() {
    }
    
    public Entity1(Entity2 ent) {
        this.entity2 = ent;
    }

    public Entity1(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Entity2 getEntity2Id() {
        return entity2;
    }

    public void setEntity2Id(Entity2 entity2Id) {
        this.entity2 = entity2Id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Entity1)) {
            return false;
        }
        Entity1 other = (Entity1) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.jakub.model.Entity1[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

Entity2

```
package com.jakub.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author André Fróes
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "str")
    private String str;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity2")
    private List<Entity1> entity1List;

    public Entity2() {
    }

    public Entity2(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public Entity2(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Entity1> getEntity1List() {
        if (entity1List == null) {
            entity1List = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return entity1List;
    }

    public void setEntity1List(List<Entity1> entity1List) {
        this.entity1List = entity1List;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Entity2)) {
            return false;
        }
        Entity2 other = (Entity2) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.jakub.model.Entity2[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

As you can notice, I didn't add the sequential strategy that you've added since you didn't post it, but should not stray far from this example. And secondly, I added in the Entity2 the list of entity1 with the mapping as well.

Pay attention that in the `manyToOne` relation in the `Entity1` I've added a cascade in order to work properly as well.

After that, all that was needed was to persist the entity and it should work without any issues, since the mapping will provide the sql for the persistence.

```
package com.jakub.service;

import com.jakub.model.Entity1;
import com.jakub.model.Entity2;
import com.jakub.repository.Entity2Repository;
import com.jakub.repository.EntityRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author André Fróes
 */
@Service
public class EntityService {
    
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository eRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private Entity2Repository e2Repo;
    
    public void saveEntity1() {
//        // Working
//        Entity1 ent1 = new Entity1(new Entity2("2"));
//        ent1.getEntity2Id().getEntity1List().add(ent1);
//        eRepo.save(ent1;
        
//        // working 2
//        eRepo.save(new Entity1(new Entity2("3")));

        // working 3
        eRepo.save(new Entity1(e2Repo.findAll().get(0)));
    }
    
    
}
```

All the examples above are working correctly. A screenshot of my DB is below with the persisted info.

[image: Persisted Data]

I've created a project on [github with this example](https://github.com/AndreFroes/jakub-example).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your anwser. Unfortunately, 3rd saving method still throws an exception "detached entity passed to persist: com.example.test.Entity2"

Comment: Have you set both to cascade all or cascade persist and merge?

Comment: I copied your code, so it's all

Comment: I've just tried the same code with mysql and the result is the same. Can I know what version of Java and Spring are you using?

Comment: Sure, the java version is 8 and the spring version is 2.6.0. I'll create a small video with it working properly. Will post in a few minutes

Comment: Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRO4FLKvG5g As you can see, before the test I perform a query in both entity1 and entity2 tables, after completion, the 3 records are correctly created

Comment: Alright, that's my fault. I thought that calling the service method in CommandLineRunner bean would have the same result as if I called it from the rest controller. It turns out, that your code works, but only if it's called from the controller. Calling it from test or configuration class result in an exception being thrown. Have you got any idea how to fix that?

Comment: update your post with the stack trace so I can analyse it as well please

Comment: If you could, before posting it, update the cascade for both classes with `CascadeType.MERGE` and check if it will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much, this change makes all 3 cases work

Comment: Sorry, I've found that I made mistake testing the code. It's still not working in test and configuration after changing to CascadeType.MERGE, and still throws "detached entity passed to persist: com.jakub.model.Entity2"

Comment: How are you handling your transaction? This message `detached entity passed to persist` means that it is decoupled from the persistence context. Have you downloaded the test project that I've set to verify or readapt it?

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded your project, tested the controller with postman (with both merge and all cascade types), added configuration class with simple CommandLineRunner that calls saveEntity1 and a test class that also calls saveEntity1. I did not do anything special with transactions